# Why i get "No route found for..."

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Hello what it is all about?
Its about setting a routing using symfony2 and why it generate "No route found for..."

Exacly it's look like this:

```
app\config\routing.yml
user:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /user/

weather:
    resource: "@WeatherBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

In my opinion it's all correct for now. We are going to talk about `@WeatherBundle`
so how my bundle's rounting looks like?
here it is:

```
.../WeatherBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
home:
    path:  /
    defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Default:index }
    methods:  [GET]

show_by_id:
    path:  /search?{type}={query}
    defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Search:id }
    requirements:
        type:  id|city

show_forecast:
    path:  /forecast?id={query}&{type}={value}
    defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Forecast:forecast, type: hours, value: 6 }
    requirements:
        type:  days|hours
        value: \d+
    methods:  [GET]
```

So is it correct ? I can't see any errors, or may it be that there is something i don't know yet about routing in symfony2 ?
now the problem:
when i type the addres: `http://localhost/app_dev.php/search?id=6295630`
so as we can see the path is: `/search?{type}={query}` where `{type}=id` `{query}=6295630` so the final form look like: `/search?id=6295630`
I'm pretty sure it should work but it's not working. it calls:

```
No route found for "GET /search"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

If you want to see full stack trace tell me.
I'm w8ing for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add query strings to your route definition this way. [Query strings](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings) are not handled as route parameters. Take a look at the [Generating URLs with Query Strings](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings) part of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

You should then replace,

```
show_by_id:
    path:  /search?{type}={query}
    defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Search:id }
    requirements:
        type:  id|city
```

by,

```
show_by_id:
    path:  /search/{type}/{query}
    defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Search:id }
    requirements:
        type:  id|city
```

and get your route parameters values within your controller as descibed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-in-action).

**Code refactoring,**

- An action called `id` doesn't mean a lot > `WeatherBundle:Search:id`.

**Update,**

In order to replace `/search?id=6295630` by `/search/[id|city]/{id}`, you've to

1 - Change your path to: `/search/{type}/{id}`
 2 - Change your `show_by_id` route requirements to:

```
  requirements:
    type:  id|city
```

3 - Change your action signature to,

```
  public function idAction($type, $id)
```

**Also**, I don't think it's a good idea to use query strings for this specific use case.
But as you asked for an example of using query strings, here's one (taken from the documentation):

Let's say you've a route that has the following path `/blog/{page}`. Calling `/blog/2?category=Symfony` will then append to your route a `category` param (as query string).

You can then access this param in your controller by calling `$request->query->get('category');` (where `$request` represents the current handled Request)

Comment: if i want there to be `?` instead of `/` what should i do ? to make it work ? In this example they are using dots: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#advanced-routing-example

Comment: There a big difference (in use) between route parameters, query stings and special routing parameters like _format. Take a deeper look at the documentation.  

As "?" and "&" are used to pass extra parameters to your route (as query strings). It's not then a good idea to use them as conventional route parameters separators.

Comment: Also if you could redirect me to some example of use ? or & please.

Answer (score 1):

Vardius please do the following ,

1. set your route like

   show_by_id:
       pattern:  /search/{id}
       defaults: { _controller: WeatherBundle:Search}
2. if you are using twig then you need to set form action as follows:

   action="{{path('show_by_id',{'id': id} )}}"
3. you will receive this id in index action of Search controller like as follows:

   public function indexAction(Request $request, $id){
   //do the work
   }

This might be solve your problem..